# Unable to find the Report Data Pane in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-2019

I'm unable to find the Report Data Pane in Visual Studio 2019.

I tried installing all relevant extensions and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> as per reports I have found on here but this hasn't seemed to do anything.

[image: Screenshot Image]

Answer (score 0):

This has now been resolved, re-imaged laptop > re-installed VS2019 with all required extensions

I believe it may have been a corrupt install of VS but this is yet to be confirmed by Microsoft